# Selecting different version of Xcode for Marmalade SDK

Tags: xcode, marmalade

On Windows there is tool to configure Marmalade.
I can't find such tool on Mac.
There must be some script to do that.

My version is of Marmalade is 6.0.6

Right now it selects Xcode 4.5 and complains that there is no iPnone SDK in Marmalade

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with xcode-select

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/
```

I wish to keep new Xcode as default but I wish to use old xcode with Marmalade only.

If someone will provide solution how to configure Marmalade to use correct version of Xcode then I mark it as correct one.